# Storyboard with NavigationController and TabController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

It seems like this should be easy to figure out, but I haven't had any luck this afternoon. I threw together this quick, simplified storyboard mockup of my problem.

Basically, I would like the table view controllers below to also be in a tab bar controller (in addition to the already present navigation controller). The tabs would switch between the two table view controllers.

Right now, the view controller with the buttons acts as a sort of menu. Each button leads to one of the table view controllers. Ideally this view controller would *not* have the tab bar visible, and would only be reachable from back buttons on the nav bars of the table view controllers.

I've tried a few different ways of embedding into a tabbarcontrollers but none of them produce the desired result:

-I've tried selecting both table view controllers and embedding those in a tab view controller. The tabbar doesnt show up in simulator, and the 'unreachable scene' warning appears.

-I've tried embedding the initial nav controller into a tabbarcontroller. This creates a tab entry for the first 'menu' page. It also causes issues with push segues once I connect the tableviews to the tabview.

I would be fine implementing some programmatic options on top of the storyboard, I just chose storyboarding for this project since it's a relatively simple presentation of data.

What is the proper way of going about this? Thanks!

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

Comment: So, do you need help adding a tab bar controller to the story board or just hiding the tab bar when your table view controllers are pushed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tab bar controller needs to be the root view controller of your view hierarchy. It goes against the HIG and Apple's standards to put a tab bar controller inside of any other type of container controller.

From the Apple docs:

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the
>   root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar
>   interface should never be installed as a child of another view
>   controller.

So, the bottom line here is you need to rethink your design. One option would be to set the `UITabBarController` as the root view of your window, and then have each of your `UITableViewController`s inside of a `UINavigationController`, which is placed inside of the `UITabBarController`. In this way, you still get the navigation bar, and stay within Apple's design guidelines (you also won't get those pesky warnings, and Apple may even be throwing an exception nowadays if you try to install a `UITabBarController` as anything other than the root view of the window).

Comment: So basically as it is set up now (with the 'menu' screen) it wouldn't be possible to do? I did try putting each tableview in it's own navigation controller, but this obviously causes problems with the segues from the buttons (tab bar doesn't appear since it wasn't a tab item that initiated the segue). The app works perfectly without any tabbar controllers, but it was brought up at a design review that adding one would require less touches to move from one option to another.

Comment: If you set the tab bar as the root view controller of the window and add the navigation controllers that contain the tableviewcontrollers to your tab bar controller, you will see both the tab bar and the nav controllers.

Comment: I ended up doing that and dropping the 'Menu' controller with the various buttons on it. I'll mark this as the answer since you got me going in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @jmstone did the same as you explained but my tab bar s not visible, can you tell me if there is any other thing required.

Answer (score 0):

I accept JMStone answer but we might get into situation where we need to put tab bar controller inside other controller especially table view controller.

Please refer [Storyboard navigation controller and tab bar controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548088/storyboard-navigation-controller-and-tab-bar-controller)

and also the good example by Matthjin: http://cl.ly/VQLa

Hopes it help some one who want to put tab bar controller inside table view controller and wants proper navigation.