# TabBarController -> NavigationController -> Multiple UIViewController (rootview controllers) using Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, tabbarcontroller

I am developing an application using storyboard that has the following structure:

```
- TabBarController (2 Tab Bars) - Initial View Controller
    o NavigationController1
       • RegistrationPage - UIViewController (candidate for rootview)
       • DoActivityPage - UIViewController (candidate for rootview)

    o NavigationController2
       • View Controller 1
```

When first time app launches, I want to show RegistrationPage to the user and on subsequent times, user will be presented with DoActivityPage. Since, both these pages are at same level, each one of them is a potential candidate to be a root view controller.

I am using Storyboard layout, so visually I can only make one of the views as rootViewController, which doesn't serve my purpose. So, I know I will have to achieve that programatically and I have tried a lot on Google but couldn't find a way to do it.

#### My question is, how do I programmatically set root view controller (out of multiple rootview controllers) for navigation controller, keeping in mind that I am using storyboard?

Presently, I see a black page when the app launches with 1st tab item selected. If I add the following code in AppDelegate.m, i see the page, but empty bottom and top bars:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
RegistrationPage *rp = [navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegistrationPage"];
navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: rp, nil];
```

@Michael I had tried similar code before, but the problem is since I am using storyboard, the only way I can access tabBarController is through this:

```
self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController];
```

And, when I tried to use the above code I get an error
    Application tried to push a nil view controller on target

Comment: Refer this link , may be it will helpfull for you



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246454/storyboard-with-navigationcontroller-and-tabcontroller

Comment: This link is not relevant to my question as I can easily control different views when presented with click of a button using prepareForSegue method. But, in my case there is no button. Its just that the root view changes on app launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the registration/login view controller is not integrated inside the tab bar.
It is a completely separate view controller (may be contained in its own navigation controller).
Once the app is launched you should check in code if registration/login should be opened and open it as modal view controller.

**EDIT**
Assuming that you have initialised `tabBarController` property, `registrationViewController` property and `isRegistered` method that returns `BOOL` in your `AppDelegate`,
Put the next code inside your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method (right before `return YES;`):

```
if ([self isRegistered] == NO) {
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
    [self.tabBarController presentViewController:navController
                                        animated:NO
                                      completion:NULL];
}
```

- There might be better place to put this code but this is the simplest to explain, assuming that I have no idea what classes you have in your project.

Comment: I understand your point that Tab Bar is not aware of Registration Controller as its part of Navigation Controller. But, in my case TabBar is aware of NavigatonController and RegistrationController is independent view. So, may be if you can post some code that would help me make RegistrationController as part of NavigationController, which I should be able to chance in runtime because as per structure highlighted above I have Registration And DoActivityPage that might want to be root view for NavigationController