# Navigation bar button unresponsive in child view controller of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I instantiate my UITabBarController by calling `navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabController"]];`

My Tab bar controller has a child view that is embedded in a navigation controller. However the bar button (`item`) is unresponsive when I touch them (the buttons in the navigation bar). I have tried logging the action but it appears as if the button is not firing at all.

The only thing that I have done differently is the way i instantiated the tab bar controller. Am I missing something?

I connected the navigation bar button from the storyboard to an action so it is hooked up successfully. Please note there is also a navigation Controller pointing to the UITabbarController not shown below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unwanted behaviour maybe because this flow (navigation controller to tabbar controller) is ill advised in the Apple HIG. More information can be found here: [Storyboard with NavigationController and TabController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246454/storyboard-with-navigationcontroller-and-tabcontroller). The solution I found was to hide the navigation bar on the navigation controller that links to the navigation bar (can be done in interface builder), then make it reappear in the new navigation controller that the tab bar links to. Confusing I know, I can help anyone who ever has a similar issue.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101381/navigation-bar-button-items-not-working-in-child-controller-from-parent-view]

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you are doing this:

```
navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabController"]];
```

You can simply drag an outlet from the UITableViewController to the UINavigationController using only the Storyboard.

Comment: Im using a third party library that was does some view progammatically. The library is a menu that instantiates all the other view this way

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the navigationItem. In the storyboard, add a navigation Item to your viewController and move your bar button items to the navigation bar that appears on the top.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work! Its so strange, its just non responsive.

Comment: Have you added the navigation bar manually by dragging and dropping or you're using the viewController's settings and changing it from inferred to have a navigation bar?

Comment: I didnt manually add the navigation bar, the viewController is still inferred, should it be changed?

Comment: no it should work the way you have it... the only thing would be the navigation item which you said you've done it. Can you post an image of your storyboard (showing the hierarchy of the views/elements on your view controller)?.

Comment: Please see above! I just added another button for testing purposes

Comment: I don't see any problem in your storyboard. There might be something wrong with the way you hooked up the action. Check if the connection is actually an IBAction and not an IBOutlet. It might sound silly but sometimes we do make mistakes of this kind :)

Comment: I know what you mean :) i tried to start over but its still the same

Comment: I found answer here that may give reason to the strange behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246454/storyboard-with-navigationcontroller-and-tabcontroller

Comment: well done @Gman! Post this as an answer. I didn't know tabbars are also like `UISplitViewController`s and need to be root always...

Comment: @DevC, I'm facing a similar issue!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101381/navigation-bar-button-items-not-working-in-child-controller-from-parent-view Suggestions are welcome...