# Different Navigation Bar Button Items in different child viewcontrollers from two container views?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uicontainerview

I have setup a `UIViewController`(RootViewController) with two container views connected to two `UITableViewController`s. Each of the `UITableViewController` is selected based on the `UISegmentedControl` in the RootViewController.

I'm able to segue as I intended to, but the bar button items in the child controllers (`UITableViewController`) are not responding.

The navigation bar button items in the two child view controllers are different from each other.

Please find a screenshot of my storyboard. (Only one child controller displayed)

[image: screenshot]

How to setup different navigation bar buttons for each of those container view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Did you [push](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller) them on the UINavigation stack?

```
 func pushViewController(ViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Well, I'm new to iOS dev, and am a little confused. I used prepareForSegue to inject my managedObjectContext, as below. if let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
                if let aViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? AViewController {
                    aViewController.mainManagedObjectContext = self.mainManagedObjectContext!
                }
            }

Comment: Should, I use your suggestion within this method or elsewhere?

Comment: @shyam Just instantiate your next view controller and push it on the navigation stack with the function in the answer. If you segue, you'll leave the navigation stack, as you've learned :)

Comment: Guess, I'm not conveying what I intend to. If I try pushing, a new instance is pushed onto the stack automatically. But, I need it only when I press one of the `UISegmentedControl` buttons. Even, the `UISegmentedControl` is lost in the process. Probably, I'm not making any sense. :-/

Comment: And, I still don't have access to the buttons.. Anyways, let me see if I can figure this out.. Thanks for your help.. :)

Comment: I tried all day in vain!! :-/ I was able to have both the `UISegementedControl` from the `RootViewController` and the bar button items from the `AViewController` appear in `AViewController`. The `UISegmentedControl` works fine, but the bar button items are still unresponsive!!