# Storyboard navigation controller and tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am trying to get the following setup in Storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

Where I have a table view in the beginning, and when I tap a cell it needs to transition to the tab bar controller, which works. But now I want a title and an extra navigation bar button in the the 2 most right controllers.

But I can't seem to drag a button to there or when setting the title, nothing shows up. How can I achieve this setup in storyboard?

---

Updated question, based on answer below.

[image: New setup]

When I have this new setup (thus with an extra navigation controller in between) I can set the title in the storyboard, but when running the app, the added title is not shown.

I have [uploaded](https://d1sz9tkli0lfjq.cloudfront.net/items/182n1Z3M201w2g1p1B12/Test.zip) a Xcode project with exactly that setup. Perhaps it can come in handy.

Comment: Is your problem solved i gt the similar issue

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For changing the `UINavigationBar` title (with no need to create 2 other `UINavigationController`) you can just use

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Title"];
```

and for adding the right button use

```
self.parentViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(myRightButton)];
```

on `viewDidLoad` method for each `UIViewController` referenced from your `UITabBarController`.

If you want to work with "navigation structures" inside your `UIViewController` from `TabItems` so you could edit your **BUFViewController.m** to that:

```
#import "BUFViewController.h"

@interface BUFViewController ()

@end

@implementation BUFViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.parentViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
}

-(void)done{
    [self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

You have to think as your `UITabBarController` is inside your parent `NavigationController`, so you want to hide the parent `UINavigationBar` and show yours.
After that, you'll be able to back to your table using `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`: on the parent's `UINavigationController`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your idea, and it works, but it also kills the "back button" which normally would appear. (Since that is added to the overlaying navigation bar). Don't know if having 2 navigation bar's is the way to go here. But with one (my first screenshot) I can't seem to add titles or buttons.

Comment: I see your edit and could add the back button in code indeed, and it works. But is there not something I am missing here? That this could be done in a more elegant way.

Comment: I've made an edit, that should work pretty for you :)

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, here is a similar approach in Swift: self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: "barButtonItemClicked:"), animated: true)

Answer (score 10):

Just in case anyone was looking for a swift approach:

```
tabBarController?.title = "Your Title"
tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "rightButtonFunction")
```

The code is best placed in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` so the title and button change as the different tabs are pressed.

You also wouldn't need the extra navigation controllers with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your test app, and I do see the title, very faintly, under the navigation bar. You can see both navigation bars if you select the tab bar controller, and uncheck the "Under Top Bars" box. However, this gives you a weird shadow on the navigation bar. I don't know if there's an easy way to fix this, but I don't think this UI with two navigation bars looks good any way. You might want to eliminate the initial navigation controller, and use a modal segue to present the tab bar controller instead. You could add a bar button item to the navigation controllers you still would have to do the dismissal of the modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace those view controllers with `UINavigationViewControllers`.

Delete the right two view controllers.

Drag drop 2 `UINavigationViewControllers` onto the storyboard and position them how you want.

Then, you need to hook those new navigation view controllers to the tab bar controller. Ctrl click and drag from the tab bar controller to the navigation controllers. Select "view controllers" from the "Relationship Segue" section of the menu that pops up. Do this for both navigation controllers.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that (I have updated my question) since that was my initial idea. Then I can place a title in the storyboard builder, but it does not show up when I am running the app.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the top bar in the attributes inspector view of your storyboard instead of using "Inferred"?

Comment: If by explicitly setting you mean using this input field, then [yes](http://cl.ly/VQGx). As you can see I can also drag a bar button out in the bar. But when running that app, nothing is shown for that view only the empty navigation bar.

Comment: You can change the title of the tabBarController to update the title while maintaining the navigation back button. `[[self tabBarController] setTitle:@"First View Controller"];`. Dirty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Overview_Register"])
    {
        WDRegisterViewController *obj=(WDRegisterViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        obj.str_Title=@"Edit Profile";
        obj.isRegister=NO;
    }
}

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Overview_Measure" sender:nil];



    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    WDPeekViewController *Peek = (WDPeekViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WDPeekViewController"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```