# which method be called-back when switching between tab bar view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbarcontroller

My initial question is:

[image]

I want to change the **navigation item** (both *title* and *button* when switching between tabs).

I tried the answer : [Storyboard navigation controller and tab bar controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548088/storyboard-navigation-controller-and-tab-bar-controller). It says:

```
self.parentViewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Title"];
```

add to **viewDidLoad** in each **view controller** works.

However, when I re-enter the view, the tile won't change. I think it means **viewDidLoad** won't get called-back when re-entering.

Any solution about [Storyboard navigation controller and tab bar controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548088/storyboard-navigation-controller-and-tab-bar-controller) ?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `viewWillAppear:`. [Here's Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:). This method will be called on the controller that is being presented, or being transitioned to. `viewWillDisappear:` ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:)) is called on the controller that is being transitioned away from.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a navigation controller for each tab in you tab bar. Then you can set your titles right in the storyboard.