# how to show second tab in Tab bar controller from another view controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to iOS and struggling with tab bar controllers in storyboard

In my app i have a dashboard in that dashboard when i click on button

"**Students**" it shows a `TableView` with list of students in `tab tar` controller

for that i took a tab bar controller with two tabs ,First tab is `Students List`

from dashboard if i click on Button "**Parents**" I want to go to `Parents` list which

is `Second tab` of a `tab bar controller`

How to go to `Second tab` of a `tab bar controller` directly when i click on `Parents`

`Edit`

thnx for ur response i'm now getting second tab directly
but the problem is i'm not getting navigation bar in top if i goto one tab 
next tab is not getting navigation bar

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboard-tutorial-create-tab-bar-controller-and-web-view/ look at this

Comment: i'm not asking to add tabs or selecting tab item index i'm asking how to connect second tab from another viewcontroller not tabbar controller

Comment: u have to do programatically.How you navigating from dashboard to students ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put in your button action method:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:/*yourIndex*/];
```

First tab has index 0. So your "Parents" tab has index 1.

Comment: thanks @Nick i have one more doubt in same scenario navigation bar in not getting for second tab if i'm in first tab and vice versa ,what could be the problem?

Comment: As I understood, all you need to do is to select the view you want to set as Navigation Controller and then Editor - Embed in - Navigation Controller. Check this storyboard structure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548088/storyboard-navigation-controller-and-tab-bar-controller

Comment: i used navigation controller for both two tabs coming fine but when i go to next view from tab1 and clicking back button it is not coming to tab1 instead its going to dashboard